# Why does the following print what it does?

Tags: c

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

unsigned int nines = 999;
byte * ptr = (byte *) &nines;


printf ("%x\n",nines);
printf ("%x\n",nines * 0x10);
printf ("%d\n",ptr[0]);
printf ("%d\n",ptr[1]);
printf ("%d\n",ptr[2]);
printf ("%d\n",ptr[3]);
```

Output:

```
3e7
3e70
231
3
0
0
```

I know the first two are just hexadecimal representations of 999 and 999*16. What do the remaining 4 mean? the ptr[0] to ptr[3]?

Comment: Try print out the values from `ptr` in hexadecimal as well.

Comment: Mostly, they mean you're using a little-endian machine, not a big-endian one. Probably an Intel machine, but not necessarily.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely you are running this on a 32 bit LE system `999` in hex is:-
`00 00 03 E7` - The way it would be stored in memory would be
`E7 03 00 00` Hence:-

`ptr[0]` points to the byte containing `E7` which is 231 in decimal
`ptr[1]` points to the byte containing `03` which is 3   in decimal
`ptr[2]` points to the byte containing `00` which is 0   in decimal
`ptr[3]` points to the byte containing `00` which is 0   in decimal

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will see clearly if you write:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

main() {
unsigned int nines = 999;
byte * ptr = (byte *) &nines;

printf ("%x\n",nines);
printf ("%x\n",nines * 0x10);
printf ("%x\n",ptr[0]);
printf ("%x\n",ptr[1]);
printf ("%x\n",ptr[2]);
printf ("%x\n",ptr[3]);
printf ("%d\n",sizeof(unsigned int));
}
```

char is 8 bits, one byte, and int is 4 bytes (in my 64 bytes machine).
In your machine the data is saved as [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)  so less significative byte is located first.

Comment: Just a complementary note: Bits inside the byte are still stored in "normal" order with the most significant bit to the left, it's the bytes that are inverted.  Little-endian is used because of performance, the same value can be read at different lengths while keeping it's meaning, with big-endian you would have to offset your pointer to have the same effect.

Comment: @Havenard I wonder if it makes sense to talk about 'bit order' inside of a byte at all, since individual bits are not addressable.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat They are numerically meaningful, of course it makes sense. It's like the difference between 123 and 321.